# Why am I getting an Error in upgrading anaconda

Tags: anaconda, upgrade

[ERROR IN UPGRADING ANACONDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnERH.png)

While upgrading Anaconda, I am getting this error and it automatically gets terminated from upgrading. Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue? It says that there is an error in eggs_info script file. How to rectify this error? Can anyone help me in solving this issue.

Comment: 1) What is the command that you ran. This looks like `pip` output, so not suited for "upgrading anaconda" 2) Please don't post images of errors. People will downvote and ignore your question this way. Always copy paste the complete relevant output (if you don't know what is relevant, copy paste the complete output) and the commands that you ran into your question. You can [edit] to improve your question